# How to show a hidden div by clicking on another div (button) in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to show the loading div that's normally hidden after clicking a confirm button, even after changing the hidden value on click.

here is my code:

```
<div class="form-btns">
  <button type="button" class="btns full-width" v-on:click="submitPhoneNumber(); isHidden = false">
   {{t('confirmNumber')}}
  </button>

  <loader title="" v-if="!isHidden"></loader>

  <button type="button" class="btns hyperlink">
   {{t('accountRecovery')}}
  </button>

</div>
```

```
data() {
    return {
      isHidden: true,
    };
```

Comment: do you get any console errors? and can you verify that the loader isn't already hidden via css

Comment: the loader is hidden because i hide it with ( v-if="isHidden" ) and if changed it shows, and i get no console errors, all i'm trying it change "!isHidden" to "isHidden" on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a little funky. Get rid of how you're trying to set the value directly in the template HTML and set it in your function in the `methods`. So your new code would be:

```
<div class="form-btns">
  <button type="button" class="btns full-width" v-on:click="submitPhoneNumber()">
  v {{t('confirmNumber')}}
  </button>

  <loader title="" v-if="!isHidden"></loader>

  <button type="button" class="btns hyperlink">
   {{t('accountRecovery')}}
  </button>

</div>
```

Then in your `methods` just toggle the value like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    isHidden: true,
  }
},
methods: {
  submitPhoneNumber() {
    this.isHidden = false; // I would probably rename this to isLoading and invert the logic
    // Other stuff...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `isHidden` value inside the `submitPhoneNumber`, either as below, or with a dedicated function that you call in the first one.

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isHidden: true
  },
  methods: {
    submitPhoneNumber() {
      this.isHidden = false;
      
      // Simulate an API response after 3s to hide the loader
      setTimeout(() => { this.isHidden = true; }, 3000);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="submitPhoneNumber()">
   Submit button
  </button>

  <p v-if="!isHidden">Loading...</p>

</div>
```